# Edit HTML of active Facebook page (chat specifically)?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, chat

Okay, so I'm sure with all the HTML/JavaScript masters on here someone will figure this out. 
Ive got this app I'm working on. The objective is this...
1) The user opens my app (objective-c/cocoa) and selects their preferred language. 
2) My app opens Facebook.com in whatever the users preferred browser is, except changes the document, in the way that all chat messages received are translated to the preferred language...

How might I go by this? Pretty much replacing the received chat message strings with new ones automatically?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just have them connect to Facebook chat from within your app?

Comment: You mean open Facebook.com in a webview in my app? Yes actually I think I will do that. But still I then need to get the chat text in that page and replace it.

Comment: No, I mean actually connect to Facebook chat programmatically. You can connect to it via the Jabber protocol and then actually be getting the text yourself instead of doing some hackish DOM manipulation like you're trying to.

Comment: Right but that's what I want to do. I don't want to put months into programming a jabber client who's ony function is translating chat messages. I just want to kind of extend facebooks functionality by intercepting Facebook messages and translating them.

Comment: I'm unsure that it's any less work to create browser plugins for each and every browser and then the "helper" application that they all have to communicate with, which is the only way I really see this working the way you're planning it to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need access to Facebook chat specifically, they expose an XMPP API that you can work with: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/ . I haven't used it personally, so I'm not sure if it fully satisfies your requirements, but it may be worth a look.